# NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Object

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This is the error I'm getting in logcat:

```
01-12 09:41:43.885: W/dalvikvm(1474): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/app/Items;
```

This is my Home.java class which is the main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        homeTextViews = new TextView[Items.HomeItem.length];
}
```

And here is the Item.java class:

```
public class Items {
    public static final String[] HomeItem = new String[] { "string1", "string2", "string3" };


}
```

Upon starting the app I get the error said above as soon as it starts, the `homeTextViews = new TextView[Items.HomeItem.length];` is the cause but I have no clue why. Anyone have any ideas?

I've also tried this but it still fails:

```
    Items items = new Items();
    homeTextViews = new TextView[items.HomeItem.length];
```

`Items.HomeItem` clearly isn't `null`, it's a `static` `final` so it shouldn't be `null`.

Comment: Have you tried to comment that line out and try if one of the other two causes the issue?

Comment: @user How is it a duplicate when `Items.HomeItem' isn't `null`? It can't be null as it has a `final` modifier.

Comment: If you are sure Items.HomeItem isn't null, then maybe it isn't causing the issue. Which leaves you with the task to find out what *is* null.

Comment: @Fildor What other two? If your talking about `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` & `setContentView(R.layout.home);` then no but they aren't the problem.

Comment: Are you 100% *sure*?

Comment: @Fildor In the logcat it tells me the exact line number which is giving me the error and `homeTextViews = new TextView[Items.HomeItem.length];` is the only code on that line.

Comment: Is your `Items` class doing some other static initialization which might fail? Could you also post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE Yeah... there was another in `Items`... which was the cause of the problem. Thanks that cleared that up.